# Display JSON data in listview yii2

Tags: json, listview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I have a question that is it possible to display JSON data in a listview in yii2?

Another question is that here is my `view` code

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <?= \yii\widgets\ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => 'listview',
    'layout' => "{pager}\n{items}\n{pager}",
  ]); ?>
</div>
```

Here is my `listview.php` file code

```
 <div data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse'<?= $model->id ?>'" id="title" class="panel-heading ads-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title"><?= $model->title ?></h4>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="button" id="'<?= $model->id ?>'" onclick="AdsPost(this)"
                class="checkin-btn btn btn-xs btn-danger"> View Ads
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my `controller` code

```
 public function actionEvent()
 {
    $connection=Yii::$app->db;
    $command = $connection->createCommand("SELECT * from Advertisement where maincategory=2 AND subcategory=5");
    $dataReader=$command->queryAll(); // execute a query SQL

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $data,

    ]);
    return $this->render('event' ,['dataProvider' => $dataProvider]);
}
```

I also tried something like this but its not working as well

```
$query = new Query();
    $query  ->select(['*'])
        ->from('Advertisement')
        ->where('maincategory=1')

    $command = $query->createCommand();

    $data = $command->queryAll();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $data,

    ]);
    return $this->render('index' ,['dataProvider' => $dataProvider]);
```

So what am i doing wrong here?
 I am asking question to handle JSON data as well because if i can send JSON data directly to the `Listview` than it makes my life very easy

And if its too complicated than i can manage with this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try both of this way

In this firts the mistake was the  assign of $data instead of $dataReader

```
public function actionEvent()
{
   $connection=Yii::$app->db;
   $command = $connection->createCommand("SELECT * from Advertisement where maincategory=2 AND subcategory=5");
   $dataReader=$command->queryAll(); // execute a query SQL

   $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $dataReader,

   ]);
   return $this->render('event' ,['dataProvider' => $dataProvider]);
}
```

or

```
$query = new Query();
$query->from('Advertisement')
    ->where('maincategory = 2 and subcategory = 5');

$command = $query->createCommand();

$data = $command->queryAll();

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $data,

]);
return $this->render('index' ,['dataProvider' => $dataProvider]);
```